# Multiple conditional classes in angular ls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add multiple classes in angular js but keep getting syntax error.

```
ng-class="{item.age > 30 ? 'over':'under','hidden':!dirList.toggle}"
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `class` that you want to conditionally apply first, and then the condition. Like this:

```
ng-class="{'over': item.age > 30, 'under': item.age < 30, 'hidden': !dirList.toggle}"
```

Read this [documentation for ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to learn more.

Comment: it doesnt work and also what if i want to use it with ternary operator ?

Comment: @Nomad You don't need to use a ternary, because the class will be applied if the expression evaluates to true. It will do nothing if it's a false expression evaluation.

Answer (score 4):

can you try

`ng-class="{'over' : item.age > 30, 'under' : item.age <30, 'hidden':!dirList.toggle}"`

Comment: Plus 1 for the correct syntax, `ng-class="{class: condition}"`